# Transparent Flash movie without wmode = transparent?

Tags: flash

I need to place a transparent Flash movie onto a page but it needs to be in `wmode` any other than `transparent`. Is it possible with some kind of transparent PNG image trick or something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you're using `wmode="direct"` so 99% it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **wmode="opaque"** ?

Comment: Please post it as a comment and not as "community wiki" article

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
   wmode="opaque"
```

**WMODE** - Possible values: window, direct, opaque, transparent, gpu. Sets the Window Mode property of the SWF file for transparency, layering, positioning, and rendering in the browser. If this attribute is omitted, the default value is "window".

Check adobe website for embedding flash in html, They list all the attributes giving a breif explanation and you find something new.